# How to call a function (non AJAX) after another function (non AJAX) finishes in Dojo?

Tags: callback, dojo, dom-events

This is not an AJAX request/response callback question...

I am building a grid using Dojo 1.5.  I am trying to `dojo.connect` expand/contract buttons with a function.  My problem is that the `grid.startup()` method seems to take a while after being called before the actual DOM nodes are created, so when I call `dojo.query` none of the DOM nodes I want to connect events and handlers to are present.

I have the grid being created inside an `init()` method, which is called by `dojo.addOnLoad()`.  I have the `connectExpandos()` method connected to `init()` via `dojo.connect("init", connectExpandos);`  This executes fine, but I need to `setTimeout()` within a while loop to wait for the grid.startup() to finish...

Anyone aware of a better way to do this?  Perhaps a `grid.startup()` callback I can hook onto?

Comment: I found a method in DataGrid called "postCreate", that according to the documentation "Overrides dijit._Widget, dojox.grid._Grid
Called after a widget's dom has been setup".  But when I include my connectExpandos method in the DataGrid constructor I get no results (no rows returned when usually many)... maybe I need to make a call to the parent methods in mine first??

Comment: Attempting to extend the postCreate method in DataGrid continues to give me no results... Looks like Im stuck with trusty old setTimeout...

Comment: You can override postCreate, just make sure to call "this.inherited(arguments);" before adding your code.

Comment: I don't overriding postCreate will work anyway because it sounds like you are saying the nodes you are looking for are not created until startup, and startup is called AFTER postCreate. Have you tried overriding startup instead of postCreate (again, be sure to call this.inherited before your code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another suggestion... it looks like the "startup" function, which is implemented in DataGrid's super class, _Grid (http://svn.dojotoolkit.org/src/dojox/trunk/grid/*Grid.js*), calls a function called render, which i believe is what actually render's the contents of the Grid. Subsequently, it looks like render calls a method "postrender" after it has finished rendering. Perhaps you could connect your method to the "postrender" method instead of "startup".

```
dojo.connect(grid, "postrender", function(){connectExpandos()})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the callback you were looking for was _onFetchComplete

```
dojo.connect(grid,'_onFetchComplete',function(event){
    alert("hello data is loaded")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just connect an event to grid startup method

```
dojo.connect(grid, "startup", function(){connectExpandos()})
```

Comment: It seems that connectExpandos fires before startup is finished, even with that modification.  I don't think dojo.connect waits for a function to complete before the event is fired... but I may be wrong.  Dojo documentation says it "Connects method to event, so that after event fires, method does too. All connected functions are passed the same arguments as the event function was initially called with. You may connect as many methods to event as needed." --This doesn't mention which part of a function execution stage is considered the event.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating the widget programatically (assuming you are not already), then just call your method after you call startup() (It seems odd to call startup() manually, but the example it shows in the source comments show calling grid.startup() manually).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var grid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({plugins : {nestedSorting: true, dnd: true, indirectSelection: true, 
   menus:{headerMenu:"headerMenuId", rowMenu:"rowMenuId",  cellMenu:"cellMenuId",selectedRegionMenu:"selectedRegionMenuId"}},
   ... }, dojo.byId('gridDiv'));
   grid.startup();
   connectExpandos();
</script>
```

Comment: Jason, thanks for the answer - this was what I was doing - startup() was not finished creating the DOM nodes by the time the dojo.query in connectExpandos ran.  Next time I will display some code...